# wordpress icons and gui not display while installing wordpress http://server_ip /wp-admin/install.php

Tags: installation

i am trying to install wordpress,
wordpress version 5.8.2,
php version 7.4.3,
mysql version 5.7,
ubuntu 20.04,
while installing during language setup
the page appears without wordpress logo
and gui , it appears as html page
any clues to fix to get wordpress icon
and graphics

[image]

Comment: What does your browser console say? Seems like styles could not be loaded - maybe your webserver is misconfigured?

Comment: there is no browser console message , checked with apache webserver config the syntax is ok